# nullable self reference with composite keys using doctrine

Tags: php, postgresql, database-design, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've got a problem with Doctrine ORM 2.5. The issue happens when I try to load instances of an entity that has an optional ManyToOne reference to itself using part of its primary key as a part of the foreign key.

The entity looks like the following:

```
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="client_id"))
     * @var Client
     */
    protected $client;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $category_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="category_id", nullable=true),
     *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="client_id", nullable=false)
     * })
     * @var Category
     */
    protected $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="translated")
     * @SAP\Mapping(fieldName="name")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;
}
```

As you can see, every child of a category must have the same client_id as its parent. 
The problem seems to be that Doctrine expects the parent to exists of the foreigen key isnt empfy ( = at least one field has a non-null value). Thats obviously always true since the FK contains a part of the PK.

Is there a way to tell Doctrine that it shouldn't try to load the parent if parent_id is null?

The only alternatives I see are changing the schema by either using an artifical auto generated pk or adding a new column for the parent_client_id and make sure it equals the client_id in PHP-land.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this is a bug as reported here: https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/4384

From the comments on that issue setting `fetch="EAGER"` resolves the doctrine `Missing value for primary key` error. Not really a great solution, but it may work for you depending on your use case.